# Open another ViewController without using a button?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, avaudioplayer

I am trying to open a ViewController2 from another ViewController1. I am not having any buttons, because the second ViewController should start after a sound has finished.

My function from ViewController1, that should call ViewController2:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying");

 //Here it should call the other ViewController

}
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: Do you know how to do it from a button? The code would be the same.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to present the view controller modally, whether you are in a navigation hierarchy, or use a custom transition.

Comment: @rdelmar I only know click on button in storyboard and then right-click and so on. But how can I do this in code?

Comment: You should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this... it's the same thing as doing it with a button:

```
 MyViewController* controller = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Comment: Trying to understand, which of the ViewController is number 1 and which is number 2?

Comment: You should put this code in ViewController1. replace MyViewController in the code I provided with ViewController2.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using story board. Right click and drag from your source button to your destination view controller and then select push.

If you want to do it in code make sure you have a navigation viewcontroller then do as the answer suggested in regards to pushing the next view.

Comment: I am not using any button!